# Rejecting Binary in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

How many times i can reject Binary, there any constraints?

i have rejected Binary three times due to some reasons, will this influence app approval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/10_ManagingYourApplications/ManagingYourApplications.html), it says that,

While your app is **waiting for review**, you can:

- Reject your binary to remove it from the Apple review queue
- Edit certain app information

So I guess, there's no problem with no. of rejection you did with the app due to some technical changes or in case you change your mind to put it on store.

It would be good if you can make a test app, and reject it around 20 times and then finally try to upload it to see Apple will allow it or not. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can reject binary so many times you want, but the time when your app approves would be counted from the last upload

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't affect future app approval. You will lose your place in the queue though so it will take a while before your app is re-reviewed.